# Unwind from UINavigationController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `MYViewController` which presets the `MYNavigationController` with a custom segue like

```
- (void)perform
{
    [self.sourceViewController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Also I have an unwind segue, like

```
- (void)perform
{
    [self.sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

In a storyboard there is a connection between `MYNavigationController` and Exit placeholder in Navigation Controller Scene – the unwind segue with identifier `unwindToVC1`.

`MYNavigationController` looks like this

```
...

- (UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{
    MYCustomUnwindSegue *segue = [[MYCustomUnwindSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier source:fromViewController destination:toViewController];

    return segue;
}

- (IBAction)unwindToVC1:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender
{
}

- (IBAction)dissmissMYNavigationController:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToVC1" sender:sender];
}

...
```

So when I call `-dissmissMYNavigationController` nothing happens. Even `-segueForUnwindingToViewController:fromViewController:identifier:` isn't called.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: present/dismissViewController... is manually showing and dismissing a modal controller. For segues, you want to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` in either both directions? Also need to make sure they are both the same type: ie.. modal or show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it wasn't clear for me how unwinding works, so

```
- (UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier 
{
    MYCustomUnwindSegue *segue = [[MYCustomUnwindSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier source:fromViewController destination:toViewController];

    return segue;
}

- (IBAction)unwindToVC1:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender
{
}
```

should be in `MYViewController`, not in `MYNavigationController`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the top ViewController from a navigator controller you have to call `popViewControllerAnimated:`. `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is used when you present a modal ViewController.

Comment: No, I want to dissmiss a NavigationViewController